# ZSH's function with parameter not working as expected

Tags: zsh, git, function

I have created a function in `.zshrc`:

```
function gc {
    git commit -m $1
}
```

but when I am trying to call this function:

```
gc "some commit message"
```

I get:

```
error: pathspec 'some commit message' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

what have I done wrong?

Comment: Put double quotes around `$1`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/

Comment: @Devon - still not working, I get the same error...

Comment: @Devon In zsh this only makes a difference when`$1` is empty.

Comment: That code alone works (except when `$1` is empty). Are you sure you don't have a stale alias or a stale definition of the function?

Comment: I'd suggest you try again after setting the `xtrace` option (`(set -o xtrace; gc "some commit message")`) to better see what's going on.